# Replace all text that displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

I want to replace all displaying text with something like "@@@@". It mean user will see all the page is full of "@@@@" instead of texts (except image, iframe or something doesn't exists in the page's HTML code).

This almost replace the html code of the page, but not effect to the tags and codes, just the text that display to user.

For example, I want to replace all the text in this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>                  
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 
        <ul><li>Nested item 1</li><li>Nested item 2</li><li>Nested item 3</li></ul>
       </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<div>DIV1</div>
<div>DIV2</div>
<span>SPAN</span>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" tabindex=3 />
  <label for="checkbox">Remember <strong>password</strong></label>
</p>
<p>Click here to <a href='register.php'>Register</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>                  
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>@@@@</li>
    <li>@@@@ 
        <ul><li>@@@@</li><li>@@@@</li><li>@@@@</li></ul>
       </li>
    <li>@@@@</li>
</ul>
<div>@@@@</div>
<div>@@@@</div>
<span>@@@@</span>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>@@@@</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@@@@</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" tabindex=3 />
  <label for="checkbox">@@@@<strong>@@@@</strong></label>
</p>
<p>@@@@<a href='register.php'>@@@@</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Some I've been tried:

Use JQuery to replace all the elements, tags (and it's child) that only contain plain text, this works fine at the beginning:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>@@@@</li>
    <li>@@@@ 
        <ul><li>@@@@</li><li>@@@@</li><li>@@@@</li></ul>
       </li>
    <li>@@@@</li>
</ul>
<div>@@@@</div>
<div>@@@@</div>
<span>@@@@</span>
```

But lately I realized that in case of elements, tags have child, it would failed:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" tabindex=3 />
  <label for="checkbox">Remember <strong>password</strong></label>
</p>
<p>Click here to <a href='register.php'>Register</a></p>
```

So I tried another way, using document.body.innerText to select all the text, but the HTML format is lost.

I was so tired. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `in case of elements, tags have child, it would failed:` can you explain this case?

Comment: You need to replace anything between a `>` and a `<` in the `body.innerHTML`

Comment: @Furqan: If there are child tags, the function would check that is not a "plain text" and ignore them (the example HTML I showed).

Comment: @ScottS: In this case: <p> hello, click <a href=""http://asd.zxc">here</a></p> my link would be lost.

Comment: @TrungDQ No, since you would only replace between any two tags (be opening or closing). You would check for the `>` and `<` symbols, **not** the opening and closing tags that are on the same parent level.

Comment: @ScottS I see what you mean, but here is a example: `<p> hello <strong>world</strong>, now kiss</p>`. According to your method, the result is: `<p> hello <strong>@@@@</strong>, now kiss</p>`, but the result I wanted is: `<p>@@@<strong>@@@</strong>@@@</p>`. I was considering about using regex but it became so much complex. Can you find out something more effective? :-(

Comment: You misunderstand me. I am posting my explanation as an answer now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code seems to work for me:

```
$('*').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim() != '';
}).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = '@@@@';
});
```

Basically, it replaces the contents of each *text* node with `@@@@`.

For a demo, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/K8544/3/

Comment: oh, perfect.  You win.  I never knew about *nodeType*.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works with almost page and I'm trying out this. Thank you!

Comment: If there is an `<iframe>` in the page, this doesn't work. Can you explain this case? Thank you! Waiting for your response, I'm nearly successful.

Comment: `<iframe>`s are somewhat special in this regard. Since I'm using `.contents()`, it *should* work, but I'm not really sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.  It's a function that replaces inner text with "***", but only if its inner HTML is equal to its inner text.  Otherwise, it calls itself recursively, navigating down the DOM until it reaches the innermost element.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function replaceChildren(node) {
            if ($(node).html() == $(node).text()) $(node).text("@@@@");
            else {
                $(node).children().each(function() {
                    replaceChildren(this);
                });
            }
        }
        replaceChildren($("body"));
    });
```

It's not perfect, but should be pretty close for most purposes.  I tried it on a Stack Overflow page, and most text got replaced.  The only place it doesn't work is where there is stray markup and text within the same tag, for example *<div>Here is some inner text <strong>and markup</strong></div>*.  Maybe this suffices for your purpose though ...

Comment: This would break most of the OP's tags.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. But anyway the code fails where you said, so it's not quite a general solution to the OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

A JQuery-only solution:

```
$("body *").contents().wrap("<obscure></obscure>");
$("obscure").each(function(i,e) {if ($(e).children().length==0) $(e).replaceWith("@@@@");}​);
$("obscure > *").unwrap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cranio/CW9jY/1/

This code wraps EVERY node with a custom tag (`obscure`); the use of `.contents()` makes sure we wrap ALSO the pure text nodes.
Then we substitute the `obscure` nodes which have no children (that were text-only nodes before) with @@@@, hence eliminating also the `obscure` tags.
Finally, we unwrap the other elements that were wrapped with `<obscure>`.

Comment: @TrungDQ let me know if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late reply. I've tried to use your code but seem like it doesn't work in almost page. Your fiddle example works fine, but when I used this code with larger HTML page, it didn't work. Blender's solution work fine for me. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can match anything between two tags - these don't have to be the same tag. For instance, `<div>aaa<a href="bbb">ccc dd</a></div>`, it would find `aaa`, replace it with `@@@`, then find `ccc dd` and replace it with `@@@ @@` by looking between `>` and the next `<`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function obscure() {
    var newhtml = document.body.innerHTML.split("<");
    for (var i=1; i<newhtml.length; i++) {
        var list = newhtml[i].split(">");
        newhtml[i] = (list[0]) + ">" + ((list[1]).replace(/[^@\s]/gim, "@"));
    }
    newhtml[0] = (newhtml[0].replace(/[^@\s]/gim, "@"));
    document.body.innerHTML = newhtml.join("<");
}
</script>
```

(Note: This does not replace whitespace, since that appeared to be causing some issues).

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I was so silly. This would work very well, seem quite complex at first but I think it is faster than the JQuery one. Thanks for your help!