# Replace Text but not inside url

Tags: jquery, dom

I have to following structure:

```
<div class='xx'>
  That is awesome!!
<a href="http://www.his-stuff.com">yodel</a>
</div>

<div class='xx'>
   can't touch this
</div>
```

Now I want to replace all occurrances of "is", no matter if they are standing alone or not. 
I made it that way:

```
$('.xx').each(function()
{
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("is","was"));
});
```

I want the following results:

> That is awesome -> That was awesome
>
> Can't touch this -> Can't touch thwas

This works, but the url containing "is" is also modified

> www.hwas-stuff.com

I do not want the url to be replaced but all others

***Info:*** I cannot use text() instead of html() because the "real" code is a bit more complex (Inserts images instead of text)

Comment: The URL is not changing - see this Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/X2ZyL/ which is your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.xx').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim() != '';
}).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace('is','was');
});
```

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/P5Zpk/1/)

*From a question I asked on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167387/1420186*

Comment: Sadly I cannot use this to insert an image. It will display the source <img src... instead

Comment: I'm sorry, but you just lost me here, i don't understand your need anymore. It's just not clear.

Comment: Your solution directed me into the right direction. I had to do some modifications described there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698673/add-html-to-text-node-extracted-via-node-nodevalue

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
<div class='xx'>
    That is awesome!!
</div>
<a href="http://www.his-stuff.com">yodel</a>
```

or:

```
<div class='the-style'>
    <div class='xx'>
        That is awesome!!
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.his-stuff.com">yodel</a>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class='foo bar'>
    <span class='is-was'>That is awesome!!</span>
    <a href="http://www.his-stuff.com">yodel</a>
</div>
```

I would prioritize fixing how you structured your html & your approach, rather than trying to find some funky way to patch the issue without really fixing it. Your future self will appreciate you more.

When creating classes, make sure they do a very specific (encapsulated) job and make the names descriptive, if you look at the twitter bootstrap library, it's an amazing example.

Comment: Sorry did not mention: I am not able to modify the html, just the script

Comment: then i would go with TrungDQ's proposition. From what I see and understand, it does what you want.